# Multi-module gradle project - Executing all Unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle

Our current set-up looks like this: One root-project with nine sub-modules, which are mixed between pure Java libraries and Android libraries.

Each of the modules contains features, one of the modules is the `main` module which builds the Android app by merging all required modules.

Each of the modules contains a lot of unit tests, and I'd like to execute them all in one gradle step. Right now I'm using `gradlew test` for this, but since (for example) the `main` module has multiple `product flavors` it is executing the unit tests in this module multiple times (for each flavor).

Ideally, I'd like to only execute the `main` module unit tests once, for a certain flavor and signing configuration, but since the `testFlavorDebug` tasks are created while evaluating the project (as far as I know) I cannot define this before actually executing the evaluation.

I've tried to find the tasks in `afterEvaluate` blocks, I've tried to loop over all modules, different combinations and ways, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly set this up.

I'd be glad if someone has some pointers or experience with a set-up like this and could help me out. If you require additional information, let me know and I'll supply them, but as far as the project set-up it's pretty straight forward in regards to the multi-module setting.

Comment: Why not just override the test method in gradle and make it only run for the main flavour?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried overwriting the `test` task in my `main` module, but it seems like this also prevents it from executing the `test` task for the other modules as well. Do you have an example? EDIT: Seems like after a `clean` it actually does execute all the unit tests.

Comment: So... it works?

Comment: Yes. If you post it as Answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the test method in your main module's build.gradle to only run the one time